# Diff between two time

Tags: ruby

How calculate the diff between two times in ruby?

For example:

I have this times as string

```
time1 = '08:00'
time2 = '12:00'
```

Lets consider time1 is positive and time2 is negative (Think like hour worked, I work 8 hours one day, and another day i missed 12 hours), I would like to do something like this:

```
diff = Time.parse(time1) - Time.parse(time2)
Time.at(diff).gmtime.strftime('%H:%M')
# expect to get something like "-04:00"
# but the result is  "20:00"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "time1 is positive and time2 is negative"?

Comment: Think like hour worked, I work 8 hours one day, and another day i missed 12 hours, now is clear?

Comment: You might find this class I wrote helpful: https://github.com/SKoschnicke/timespan/blob/master/time_of_day.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what’s wrong with your code, let’s execute it one by one:

```
▶ Time.parse('08:00') - Time.parse('12:00')
# => -14400.0
```

Seconds, huh. Fine.

```
▶ Time.at(Time.parse('08:00') - Time.parse('12:00'))
=> 1969-12-31 21:00:00 +0100
```

Wow. So, `Time.at` is not a method of our dream. Furthermore, I don’t know the way in standard library to get hours in format `%H:%M` from count of seconds. But:

```
▶ sprintf "%+03i:%02i", -14400 / 3600, -14400 / 60 % 60 # hours, minutes
# => "-04:00"
```

The only problem remains is a sign. The summing up:

```
▶ time1 = '06:28'; time2 = '12:00'
▶ diff = Time.parse(time1) - Time.parse(time2)
▶ sprintf "%+03i:%02i", (diff / diff.abs) * (diff.abs / 3600), diff.abs / 60 % 60
# => "-05:32"
```

Hope it helps.

**UPD:** for those, who likes monkeypatching:

```
class Time
  def diff_hours other
    return nil unless Time === other
    diff = self - other
    sprintf "%+03i:%02i", (diff / diff.abs) * (diff.abs / 3600), diff.abs / 60 % 60
  end  
end  
# => :diff_hours
▶ Time.parse('06:32').diff_hours Time.parse('12:00')
# => "-05:28"
```

Comment: nearly so, when the result is -19920.0, sprintf .... returns "-5:1680" instead "-05:32" (Correct)

Comment: I’m really sorry, I misunderstood how ruby deals with negatives division and modulo. The correct version is up.